# How to make MySql use default sock on AWS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am working on a project that needs MySql to use the default sock. The project is hosted on a AWS EC2 node.

Currently I have this error:

```
$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

The `mysqld` is running. Here is proof:

```
$ ps aux | grep mysql
root      4063  0.0  0.0  66116  1356 ?        S    Dec18   0:00 /bin/sh /var/lib/data/opt/sugarcrm-6.4.0/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/var/lib/data/opt/sugarcrm-6.4.0/mysql/my.cnf --port=3306 --socket=/var/lib/data/opt/sugarcrm-6.4.0/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock --datadir=/var/lib/data/opt/sugarcrm-6.4.0/mysql/data --log-error=/var/lib/data/opt/sugarcrm-6.4.0/mysql/data/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/lib/data/opt/sugarcrm-6.4.0/mysql/data/dev-play02.pid --lower-case-table-names=1
mysql     4311  0.0  0.9 319632 36976 ?        Sl   Dec18   0:00 /var/lib/data/opt/sugarcrm-6.4.0/mysql/bin/mysqld.bin --defaults-file=/var/lib/data/opt/sugarcrm-6.4.0/mysql/my.cnf --basedir=/var/lib/data/opt/sugarcrm-6.4.0/mysql --datadir=/var/lib/data/opt/sugarcrm-6.4.0/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/var/lib/data/opt/sugarcrm-6.4.0/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --lower-case-table-names=1 --log-error=/var/lib/data/opt/sugarcrm-6.4.0/mysql/data/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/lib/data/opt/sugarcrm-6.4.0/mysql/data/dev-play02.pid --socket=/var/lib/data/opt/sugarcrm-6.4.0/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock --port=3306
16777227 20011  0.0  0.0  61228   772 pts/0    S+   10:59   0:00 grep mysql
```

The `ps` output above is what I get by default when I login the EC2 node. As you can see, the sock is a custom one as in the parameter `--socket=/var/lib/data/opt/sugarcrm-6.4.0/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock`.

So, my question is: how can I make MySql use the default sock `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` when I login the node? Thank you very much.

BTW, I believe the EC2 node is running RedHat linux.

**Update**
Per nrathaus's suggestion, the `my.cnf` file might be the suspect. So, here is the full content of `/etc/my.cnf` on the EC2 node:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# Semisynchronous Replication
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-semisync.html
# uncomment next line on MASTER
;plugin-load=rpl_semi_sync_master=semisync_master.so
# uncomment next line on SLAVE
;plugin-load=rpl_semi_sync_slave=semisync_slave.so

# Others options for Semisynchronous Replication
;rpl_semi_sync_master_enabled=1
;rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout=10
;rpl_semi_sync_slave_enabled=1

# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema.html
;performance_schema


[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, locate the references to `socket=` and make sure they all point to the same place.

In your case, it should be changed from:

```
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

To

```
socket=/var/lib/data/opt/sugarcrm-6.4.0/mysql
```

Comment: .@nrathaus: Thanks a lot for the answer. I didn't find `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, but I do find this file `/etc/my.cnf`. However, I didn't see anything suspicious in that file. I posted the full content of that file in my question.

Comment: Actually you can see that it points to `socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` rather than `/var/lib/data/opt/sugarcrm-6.4.0/mysql` so why not change your my.cnf to point to the right spot?

Comment: .@nrathaus: Thank you very much. You idea sounds good. However, I solved the problem in a different way. I killed the `mysqld` process, and restarted MySql with `mysqld_safe`, and now everything is working. In any case, your help is greatly appreciated. :-)

Comment: Reboot the server and make sure your solution works post-boot

Comment: .@nrathaus: OK. My solution doesn't work after reboot, even after I replaced all the sockets with `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` in `/var/lib/data/opt/sugarcrm-6.4.0/mysql/my.cnf`. Nevertheless, your solution of replacing socket in `/etc/my.cnf` with `/var/lib/data/opt/sugarcrm-6.4.0/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock` works, but I lose all my databases and users in that way.

Comment: .@nrathaus: I finally got everything working using the solution in your second comment. So, can you edit your answer to incorporate that comment so that I can accept it, please? Thanks.